# XPAGES - left align place bar buttons

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-extlib

By default, nodes added to the Place Bar on the Application Layout Control are displayed on the right hand side of the Place Bar. Is it possible to instead display the nodes on the left hand side of the Place Bar?

Comment: But buttons in Place Bar are already displayed on right hand side! 'Place name' appears on left hand side of Place bar.

Comment: sorry, got right and left mixed up :-( Fixed that now.

Comment: You also need to update the title :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do not change the default cssfiles on the server. Create a new theme extending your oneuiv2 default theme and styles. Then add a custom.css for your application where you overwrite what you want to change in the default css:

Theme:

```
<theme extends="oneuiv2.1">
    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>custom.css</href>
    </resource>
</theme>
```

custom.css:

```
.lotusPlaceBar .lotusBtnContainer {
    float: left;
}
```

This will give you a better overview and lets you customize oneuiv2 for your needs

Answer (score 3):

You can modify the CSS classes used by Application Layout control to move the place bar buttons left.

```
.lotusPlaceBar .lotusBtnContainer {
    float: left;
}
```

Take help of [Google Developer Tools](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) to inspect Application Layout control and find out more of its CSS classes.

Comment: I've looked for this in oneuiv2/defaulttheme/defaulttheme.css (I'm using the oneuiv2 theme) but didn't find it. Can you tell me in which file this style is contained?

Comment: I don't think you will find these classes in those CSS. They are part of extension library.